# Using bsearch() function with array of structs in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, bsearch

I have an array of structs and I would like to find a key that is an integer in the array of structs.
My structure looks like this:

```
typedef struct{
    int x;
    int y;
    int area;
    int occurence;
}pair;
```

And I would like to use `bsearch()` to find that specific value in the array that is the area. I have an array of pairs sorted by `qsort()` in ascending order. My code looks like this:

```
qsort(pairs, nPairs, sizeof(pair), cmpArea);

int * tmp = NULL, area = someValue; 
tmp = (int *)bsearch(&area, pairs, nPairs, sizeof(pair), cmpArea);

if (tmp!=NULL)
   //do something
else
   //do something

//pairs is the name of the array, nPairs is number of elements
```

I tried to look at the values using a debugger, and `bsearch()` always returns NULL not sure why. I doubt that my compare function is the problem, but it looks like this :

```
int cmpArea(const void *a, const void *b){

    pair * pairA = (pair*)a;
    pair * pairB = (pair*)b;

    return (pairA->area - pairB->area);
}
```

I tried different comparing functions, but none works. I´m opened to your ideas. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please post a [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, construct a simple example that illustrates your problem. People need to be able to see and run actual code that can repro the problem (details matter). And you may even find the problem yourself as part of creating the minimal code.

Comment: The first arg to `bsearch` looks wrong. It should be a pointer to an object that contains  the key (not a key value itself).

Comment: I found this syntax at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/bsearch/ in their example. But I will try to use your suggestion.

Comment: @CherryTW The example uses an array of ints and hence it is correct in that case for the key to point to an int. In your case you have an array of structs.

Comment: How is `pairs` declared and allocated? (as a single block (simple array or single-allocation) or pointers to `pair` with separate allocations)  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are pointing to a key value and not an actual member object.

The call to `bsearch` should be more like this:

```
pair key_obj;
pair *result;
key_obj.area = someValue;
result = bsearch(&key_obj, pairs, nPairs, sizeof(pair), cmpArea);
```

It was pointed out to me that the first arg could point to an `int *` if the comparator was written to handle that. In that case we would have:

```
int key_obj = someValue;
pair *result;

result = bsearch(&key_obj, pairs, nPairs, sizeof(pair), cmpArea);

int cmpArea(const void *a, const void *b){

    int *key = (int *)a;
    pair * pairB = (pair*)b;

    return (*key - pairB->area);
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for an explanation I haven`t realized that I have wrong matching type of the key.

Comment: Also I would set the other variables of math_this to 0.